# Including custom javascript files in Office add-in deployment

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am creating a number of Office add-ins for Word and Outlook at the moment. As I an trying to keep the code manageable, I am using 3rd party js files as well as my own. Unfortunately, these extra files are not transferred and appear as unfound files errors when the add-in starts.

What am I doing wrong and what should I be considering when trying to solved this problem?

Comment: Are you loading the files in your HTML page using `<script>` tags?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It seems that packaging the add-in correctly places all the javascript files along with the taskpane.js/.html. Debugging does not look in the same location as the taskpane.js/.html for the additional js files.

Comment: Please show the code or markup where you are loading the 3rd party files. Also, when the add-in is running, try pasting it's full URL into a browser window and use the browser tools to see if the 3rd party files are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

After considering the project location, the web addresses, etc., it is required that the external javascript files (and additional html files) are present along side the manifest.xml when debugging. The taskplane references the javascript files relative to itself in the development location (src\taskpane) i.e.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
```

however to debug the add-in, the client.js file must also be in the project root beside the manifest.xml.

Obviously, the other option is to include the external javascript code in your taskpane.js :-)